# How to eliminate smoothing in matplotlib (pyplot)?

Tags: matplotlib, graphics, julia

I am doing some colormap plot using the Julia implementation of PyPlot. I want the figure to be without any interpolation or smooting, and I want it to be saved as svg so it can be manipulated afterwards by other people. In the Jupyter notebook it appears as I want it to appear, and if I save it as png it gets saved as I want. But if I save it as svg, the colormap gets smoothed, which is plainly wrong for my data. 
The code is:

```
figure(figsize=(7.0, 5.5))
PyPlot.xlim(1,64)
PyPlot.ylim(1,64)
otraimagen=imshow(EjemploModificado, cmap="bwr", interpolation="none", origin="lower", vmin=-limites, vmax=limites, extent=[1,64,1,64])
use_gridspace='True')
use_gridspec="True",fraction=0.045 )
tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=14)   
xlabel("electrode number", fontsize=14)
ylabel("electrode number", fontsize=14)
savefig("CSD-Neg-Pos-$t.png", dpi=90) 
PyPlot.close_queued_figs()
```

The images produced are, as png:
[image]

and as svg (converted afterwards to png so I could uplotad it here):
[image]

Comment: This is actually [an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4136/) in `matplotlib` (now closed). As suggested, try setting `svg.image_noscale` to `False`

Comment: Well, I just tried both settings (true and false), and they give the same result, the smeared appearence that I do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, in addition to the SVG-specific issue that @FelipeLema mentioned, there's another point that you should be aware of.

There is a difference between `interpolation='none'` and `interpolation='nearest'`.   It mostly applies to vector formats, where you'll be using a viewer to produce a rasterized version that's displayed on-screen (e.g. PDF, SVG).

There's a nice visual summary in the matplotlib example here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_none_vs_nearest.html  In this case, we'd be talking mostly about the "small image blown up" portion of the example.

`interpolation='none'` tells the viewer that there's no specific interpolation type required.  For raster images produced by matplotlib, it will be nearest interpolation. For some PDF viewers this is nearest, and for others it's bilinear or another smooth interpolator.

However, `interpolation='nearest'` specifies that you specifically want nearest-neighbor interpolation.

I don't recall offhand whether SVG viewers behave in a similar way as PDF viewers in this specific regard, but even with the bug that @FelipeLema mentioned fixed, you may not see nearest-neighbor interpolation in all SVG viewers with `interpolation='none'`.

Comment: I think that is not it. There's a difference between `None` (which means default, which is what you are referring) and `none` which means absolutely no interpolation at all, which is what I want. See the examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html).

Comment: No, `None` is entirely different from the string `"none"`. There's no such thing as "no interpolation". What you mean is nearest neighbor interpolation. However, that may not affect your specific issue at all.